# How do I list, organize, or navigate between jQuery events in WebStorm/PhpStorm?

Tags: jquery, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-organization

I've been struggling with navigating my code in WebStorm/PhpStorm. When I'm editing a large page, in the JavaScript section I naturally seem to have 3 sections:

1. `$( document ).ready()` code
2. Page events (using jQuery)
3. Functions

The biggest problem I'm having is once I get like 20 jQuery events on a page, it becomes very hard to navigate and find the event I'm looking for.

I really want something like the Structure panel, which honestly seems pretty useless right now because it doesn't seem to be able to pick up jQuery events but picks up random code elements instead. Or I'd love something like <kbd>Alt + Down</kbd> and <kbd>Alt + Up</kbd> to navigate to the next or previous functions, but that only works with functions and not jQuery events.

Is there a way to list or navigate between code sections that can identify jQuery events in code? Perhaps a plugin? Or maybe a better way I can structure my code to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did find a solution to this. What I did was wrap all my events (including the code I want to run on document ready) in individual functions all within a single object. Then, in an actual document ready call, I cycle through every function in the object and call it to initialize my events. I also threw all the functions on the page into their own object for consistency, but that would certainly be optional.

This has made my code easier to read (since I have well named event functions and there is now no loose code in my Script tag - it's all within functions) and the Structure tab in PHPStorm now includes JQuery events and is neatly organized too. It has really improved my ability to navigate my code.

## What It Looks Like

I'll use a bit of example code here to show what I did. Keep in mind that this code is dirt simple compared to some of the more complex pages I've been working on that can be thousands of lines of code, so the level of organization this has added to my code has been much more drastic than I can show in this simple example.

**Here's what my code used to look like:**

```
<script>

    console.log("I'd often have random code here outside any function that cluttered the Structure panel");

    $(function () {
        f.updateResults("Type something in the input to change this text!");

        $("#myBtn").click(function () {
            f.alertThis("You clicked a button!")
        });

        $("#myInput").change(function () {
            f.updateResults($(this).val());
        });
    };

    function alertThis (val) {
        alert(val);
    }

    function updateResults() {
        $("#results").text(text);
    }
</script>
```

When this got to be 20 events and almost as many functions, it became very hard to find what I was looking for and the Structure panel was a mess of random elements that were completely useless.

**Now my code looks like this:**

```
<script>
    jsinit

    e._ready = function () {
        console.log("Any loose page code I now put in here. This is automatically run first when the document is ready");
        f.updateResults("Type something in the input to change this text!");
    };

    e.myBtn_click = function () {
        $("#myBtn").click(function () {
            f.alertThis("You clicked a button!")
        });
    };

    e.myInput_change = function () {
        $("#myInput").change(function () {
            f.updateResults($(this).val());
        });
    };

    f.alertThis = function (val) {
        alert(val);
    };

    f.updateResults = function (text = false) {
        $("#results").text(text);
    };
</script>
```

The line that says jsinit is a collapsable comment as mentioned in the answer by lena. It has a bit of code I now put once per page when needed via a [live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html). That code looks like this when it isn't collapsed:

```
//region jsinit
window.g = (typeof g !== "undefined") ? g : [];
var e = {};
var f = (typeof f !== "undefined") ? f : {};
g.push(e);
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        for (var page_index in g) {
            if (typeof g[page_index]._ready !== "undefined")
            {
                g[page_index]._ready();
                delete g[page_index]._ready;
            }
            for (var func_index in g[page_index])
            {
                g[page_index][func_index]();
            }
            delete g[page_index];
        }
    },0);
});
//endregion
```

This code could be simplified quite a bit, but I wanted to handle the special case of when you include a page within another page (such as when opening a JQueryUI dialog and loading its contents with another page via ajax). In these circumstances, the e and f variables will already exist and there will be two _ready functions, so you can have some odd bugs that crop up if you don't handle it. That's what the loops and checks for existing variables are for. The setTimeout line is just to handle a bug in the older version of JQuery I'm using and isn't necessary in v3 of JQuery or newer.

## What It Does

You'll notice how it's much easier to just browse down the line looking for the function or event you need. All the code is contained in functions as well and nothing is ever loose anymore.

Like I mentioned, the functions wouldn't need to be put in their own object, but I did it for consistency. It also has the added benefit of easily being able to narrow autocomplete down to just your local functions by typing f and then a period.

Not only do I feel the code is much easier to read now, but here's what the structure panel looks like now:

[image]

All my events listed and all my functions are listed and easy to jump to. This panel used to look like a jumble of worthless information.

**For example, here's one of my pages with the old structure panel:**

[image]

**This is the structure panel for the *exact same page* after I organized it in this manner:**

[image]

I've got all my events nicely listed and I can quickly browse wherever I need to go.

## Live Templates That Make This Easy

If you're interested in doing something similar, I created 3 live templates to make this organization super easy. You can add a live template by pressing Ctrl+Alt+S and going to Editor > Live Templates.

I added this one under the html/xml scope so that I can quickly type js and press Tab to create a script tag with the jsinit code already included:

```
<script>
    //region jsinit
    window.g = (typeof g !== "undefined") ? g : [];
    var e = {};
    var f = (typeof f !== "undefined") ? f : {};
    g.push(e);
    $(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            for (var page_index in g) {
                if (typeof g[page_index]._ready !== "undefined") {
                    g[page_index]._ready();
                    delete g[page_index]._ready;
                }
                for (var func_index in g[page_index]) {
                    g[page_index][func_index]();
                }
                delete g[page_index];
            }
        }, 0);
    });
    //endregion$collapse$

    e._ready = function () {
        $END$
    };
</script>
```

The cursor is first at the end of the collapsible custom region. I then press Ctrl+Alt+- to collapse it and press Tab to have my cursor jump right into the _ready function (that's what the $collapse$ and $END$ variables in the template do).

I also added the following to the JavaScript scope so I can add the jsinit code to existing scripts without including the script tags. Since they are in different scopes, they both can be activated with the same abbreviation (js), so I don't even have to think about whether I want to wrap it in script tags or not:

```
//region jsinit
window.g = (typeof g !== "undefined") ? g : [];
var e = {};
var f = (typeof f !== "undefined") ? f : {};
g.push(e);
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (var page_index in g) {
            if (typeof g[page_index]._ready !== "undefined") {
                g[page_index]._ready();
                delete g[page_index]._ready;
            }
            for (var func_index in g[page_index]) {
                g[page_index][func_index]();
            }
            delete g[page_index];
        }
    }, 0);
});
//endregion$collapse$

e._ready = function () {
    $END$
};
```

Last, since I'm creating a bunch of functions now, I just made a simple script so that I can type the function name, f, and then Tab to quickly create a function:

```
= function ($params$) {
    $END$
};
```

It's not necessary but I found it saves a lot of time.

**EDIT:**

One more thing I did that made navigating with this system really easy. I rebound the File Structure search window to Ctrl+WinKey. You can find this keymap by going to Keymap under settings and browsing to Main Menu > Navigate > File Structure.

Now I can press Ctrl+WinKey and just start typing a function name to quickly jump to it. Since my JQuery events are now wrapped in functions, I can also quickly find and jump to any event the same way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, and I'm not aware of any plugins for this:(

You can try using custom regions here: surround each of your events with `// region <Event name> ... // endregion` comments and then use **Navigate | Custom Folding...** (`Ctrl+Alt+.` in default keymap) to navigate to the desired region by name

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It taught me something I never knew existing in PHPStorm/WebStorm. I actually did find a nice solution to this problem and answered my own question, but I mentioned you in the answer because I do use a collapsible comment in my solution!